# Is there a way to scroll back in terminal to a specific command?

Tags: command-line, scrolling

I have a terminal command which gives me very long output and I want to check this output from the very first line of it. So far I have to scroll with the mouse and try to catch it, which is quite annoying (especially if I executed this command few times). Is there a way to scroll the output to, say, last executed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of said program to a pager program or a file that you can scroll through at your leisure.

To the `less` pager: `the-program --args 2>&1 |less`

To a file: `the-program --args 2>&1 >> output.log`

Comment: what does 2>&1 stands for?